# How to find the area of a quarter circle given only the perimeter of a quarter circle?

Tags: circles, area

I have been looking for a formula for these types of problems but I still haven't gotten an answer. The question you guys can use can be found [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gXJb9.png). All I need is the formula but if you want you can include the answer for the question. Also if you find the formula for a semicircle then please include that. Be sure to keep in mind that you need to include $2r$ in your formula.

Also if you are confused please tell me so I  know whether I should elaborate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The perimeter of a full circle is $2\pi r$.  The perimeter of a quarter circle is therefore $P = \frac {2\pi r}4 + 2r$.  The formula for the area of a full circle is $\pi r^2$.  The area of a quarter circle is therefore $A= \frac {\pi r^2}4$.

So solve for $r$ in terms of $P$ and plug that equation into $A$.

I assume you can do that yourself.

Comment: If we were to use a semi circle would the fraction be changed to $ \pi r$ Sorry I'm not good with the math formatting.

Comment: Um, you tell me.  What is half of $2\pi r$?

Comment: Nvm. I got the answer, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First find the radius of the circle using the perimeter.  For the quarter circle, the perimeter is made up of two lots of the radius plus a quarter of the circumference, so we have that
$$2r + \frac{\pi}{2} r = P$$
giving that $$r = \frac{2P}{4 + \pi}$$
Now that you have the radius, you can use the area of a quarter circle formula to get the answer.

Comment: I do not understand why you included $$\frac{\pi}{2} r$$ in the equation. Will you please explain?

Comment: Because $\frac {\pi}2r $ is a quarter of the circumference of the full circle.  Just like he said immediately in the sentence above.

Comment: " the perimeter is made up of two lots of the radius plus a quarter of the circumference,"  "two lots of the radius" = 2r.  "a quarter of the circumference" = $\frac {\pi}2r$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint -

$\frac14 \times 2\pi r + 2r = 5.355$

Find value of r.

Then put it in.

Area = $\frac14 \times \pi r^2$